# Passing query string to external JS script

Tags: javascript

People come to my site with the Clickbank hoplink query string (?hop=xxxxx) This needs to be sent to a script on my server so it can be converted to "letter-letter-number-number" (a Reference Code to original xxxxx username)

The way I'm doing this at present it is:

1. Use one script to read the query string
2. Use another SRC to send that to my server, which sets a cookie, (and returns a value)
3. (Another replace script to change all old_Reference_Codes to the
       new Reference Code)

** The parts in brackets haven't been attempted yet!!

Now, to keep things neat, I want to place these routines in an external .js file ... but I have found that in doing this, the script cannot see the search string. (works OK if in main HTML)

Here's what I've got thus far:

```
var page=location.search.substring(5);
document.write('<img width="0px" height="0px" src="/cgi-bin/dbase/conv_hop.pl?'+page+'">');
//document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/aa00/g, "new_ref_code");
```

The part behind comments hasn't been tried yet. It will (hopefully) replace all instances of "aa00" on HTML page with say new Ref Code of "BC98". As is, the conv_hop.pl was simply used to create a cookie on the server, but has now got to return a value to be used in the next part, maybe something like

```
var new_ref_code.src="/cgi-bin/dbase/conv_hop.pl?'+page (Complete guess here)
```

So what's the question?

Is there a way to pass the query string to the external JS file? And what method should I use to get the data sent back via conv_hop.pl so it's value is usable by the commented part